# Indexing Data.Vector with an array of indices

Tags: haskell

Is it possible in Haskell to index a Vector A from `Data.Vector` using another Vector of Integers B, i.e. `A[B] = [ A[B[0]], A[B[1]], ... ]`? It seems to be planned for further versions as the [Vector tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial), section 2.11 suggests.

Of course, one can always write some function to do this, but this would involve a lot of copying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is advisable to use [`backpermute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.11.0/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#v%3abackpermute) which essentially is `map (xs!)` but more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `map` and `(!)`,

```
index :: Vector a -> Vector Int -> Vector a
index as bs = map (as!) bs
```

Comment: Exactly. But this is what I meant by "write some function". The answer from @choener uses the library function (which is likely to be more optimized) and is, therefore, better from my perspective.